# Grabbing selector value from a tag

Tags: javascript

In short:

This code:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= items.length; i++){
    console.log(items[i])
}
```

Returns me this data:

```
<a class="photo ajax2" target="_blank" href="/profile/show/3209135.html" data-first="1" data-next="3206884">
<a class="photo ajax2" target="_blank" href="/profile/show/3206884.html"  data-next="3209135">
<a class="photo ajax2" target="_blank" href="/profile/show/3209135.html" data-next="3209755">
```

I want to grab the `data-next` values from all links. How can I do that ? I've tried this:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= items.length; i++){
    console.log(items[i].querySelector('a["data-next"]'));
}
```

but this doesn't work. I need this only with vanilla JS.

**ANSWERED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items[i]` refers to the element itself, thus `querySelector()` on that will return nothing. Try with [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
console.log(items[i].getAttribute("data-next"));
```